# React native expo splash screen issue on production

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built an app on React Native, the app works fine in the development mode but it sticks on the splash screen in the production build.

```
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2"
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
```

Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, LogBox } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import TabsBar from "./src/components/TabsBar";
import StarterPage from "./src/pages/StarterPage";
import LoginPage from "./src/pages/auth/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./src/pages/auth/RegisterPage";
import { getCache } from "./src/utils/cache";
import { store } from "./src/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import LessonDetailsPage from "./src/pages/LessonDetailsPage";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "./i18n";
import ChatPage from "./src/pages/ChatPage";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// Ignore all log notifications:
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [language, setLanuage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        const value = await getCache("language");
        setLanuage(value);
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (value) {
          i18n.changeLanguage(value == "TR" ? "tr-TR" : "en-US");
        } else {
          i18n.changeLanguage("en-US");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }
    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View onLayout={onLayoutRootView} style={styles.container}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={language ? "TabsBar" : "StarterPage"} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
              <Stack.Screen name="TabsBar" component={TabsBar} />
              <Stack.Screen name="StarterPage" component={StarterPage} />
              <Stack.Screen name="LoginPage" component={LoginPage} />
              <Stack.Screen name="RegisterPage" component={RegisterPage} />
              <Stack.Screen name="LessonDetailsPage" component={LessonDetailsPage} />
              <Stack.Screen name="ChatPage" component={ChatPage} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  splashContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```